# How to make rotating animation in css with fixed position?

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to accomplish animation with a star that spins without moving its position. Im doing it with :before, since i cant refactor html.

Here is the code:

```
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.top_bar_links_container>:first-child::before
{
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml,%20%20%20%20%20%20<svg%20xmlns%3D"http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg"%20viewBox%3D"0%2C0%2010%2C10">%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20<polygon%20fill%3D"%23209fdf"%20points%3D"5%2C%200%205.8419%2C%202.96747%208.53553%2C%201.46447%207.03253%2C%204.1581%2010%2C%205%207.03253%2C%205.8419%208.53553%2C%208.53553%205.8419%2C%207.03253%205%2C%2010%204.1581%2C%207.03253%201.46447%2C%208.53553%202.96747%2C%205.8419%200%2C%205%202.96747%2C%204.1581%201.46447%2C%201.46447%204.1581%2C%202.96747"%20/>%20%20%20%20%20%20</svg>%20%20%20%20');
    display: table-caption;
    width: 25px;
    height: 17px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}
```

From what i have done so far, the animation works but not in the way i want it to be.

[Looks like the start should be aligned in the center but i cant do it for some reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SV1o.png)

Answer (score 0):

create new element,

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

and try this css,

```
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I fotgot to mention i cant touch the html. Thats why i use :before.

Comment: try this ->     .top_bar_links_container {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}